# Visual Studio C# connecting Azure blob and fileshare storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, visual-studio-2022, azure-file-share

I want to include in my application, written in Visual Studio 2022 using C#, a connection to Azure Cloud blob storage / fileshare storage and copy files there.

I have also found a tutorial at Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/azure/vs-azure-tools-connected-services-storage?view=vs-2022) but it doesn't help me, it doesn't work like that.

Can someone explain what I need to do and how or does anyone have a code example?

Many thanks in advance,
Michael

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to upload a text file into the azure blob storage by creating a `c#` console application in Visual Studio 2022 and created an Azure storage account in Azure portal with a container inside to upload file from `C#` code as shown in the below screenshot:

[image]

***Initially the container is empty:***
[image]

I have created a Console project with .net core 6.0 in VS and added the `azure storage blobs` package through nuget package manager and installed successfully as shown below:
[image]

After creating the project then we need to add a class library to the project.
Right click on project in solution explorer-->add-->class-->Add as shown below:

[image]

Use the below `C#` code to upload a file into the Azure blob storage container:

**Class1.cs** :

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace AzureBlobStorageClient
{
    public class AzureBlobClient
    {
        public static async Task UploadBlob()
        {
            var connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=rkteststorageaccount;AccountKey=**********4x/QqxKNyxna89+Zzh9r+***Q==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
            string containerName = "rkcontainer";
            var serviceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
            var containerClient = serviceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
            var path =  "c:\\Temp";
            var fileName = "Testfile.txt";
            var localFile = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
            await File.WriteAllTextAsync(localFile, "This is a test message");
            var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);
            Console.WriteLine("Uploading to Blob storage");
            using FileStream uploadFileStream = File.OpenRead(localFile);
            await blobClient.UploadAsync(uploadFileStream, true);
            uploadFileStream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: Replace the Azure storage account connection string (copy from the azure portal) and container name with your storage details the above code.

**program.cs:**

```
using AzureBlobStorageClient;
using System;
await AzureBlobClient.UploadBlob();
Console.ReadKey();
```

Build the project and run the above code then it will upload a file in the Azure storage blob container successfully as shown below:

[image]

***Output screen after uploading the file to Azure container:***
[image]